# How to get specific array objects from different documents in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm getting an issue. The problem is, I've multiple collections each collection has dimension field, that contains array of objects of different dimensions. The collection looks something like below.

[image]

Now I need to return only specific object from array by slug, the ids can be from multiple documents.

I been using the below query to filter but it's returning me whole document. Here's my query

```
db.dimensions.find({
    "dimension.dimensionChildSlug": { $in: ["spring", "formal"] } 
}).select({ dimension: 1 })
```

But the expected result should be like this, only the items from array which matches the slug will be retrived.

```
[
    {
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423b71df226c91a55d756bb"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Spring",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "spring",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "spring"
    },
{
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423cde4f4db0d397b22390b"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Wedding",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "wedding",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "wedding"
    }
]
```

please find the collection

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6423b6faf226c91a55d756b9"
  },
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isArchived": false,
  "dimensionType": "Collections",
  "dimensionTypeSlug": "collections",
  "dimensionTypeToLower": "collections",
  "dimension": [
    {
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423b71df226c91a55d756bb"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Spring",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "spring",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "spring"
    },
    {
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423b723f226c91a55d756bc"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Summer",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "summer",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "summer"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2023-03-29T03:56:42.370Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2023-03-29T03:57:23.419Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6423cddbf4db0d397b22390a"
  },
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isArchived": false,
  "dimensionType": "Occassions",
  "dimensionTypeSlug": "occassions",
  "dimensionTypeToLower": "occassions",
  "dimension": [
    {
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423cde4f4db0d397b22390b"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Wedding",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "wedding",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "wedding"
    },
    {
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423ce0af4db0d397b22390c"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Business Casual",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "business casual",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "business-casual"
    },
    {
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isArchived": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6423ce18f4db0d397b22390d"
      },
      "dimensionChild": "Formal",
      "dimensionChildToLower": "formal",
      "dimensionChildSlug": "formal"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2023-03-29T05:34:19.300Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2023-03-29T05:35:20.294Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Can anyone please help me to fix that.

Thanks.

Comment: did you mean to get formal instead of wedding

Comment: how about unwind,match,project in an aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      "dimension.dimensionChildSlug": {$in: ["spring", "formal"]}
  }},
  {$project: {
      dimension: {$filter: {
          input: "$dimension",
          cond: {$in: ["$$this.dimensionChildSlug", ["spring", "formal"]]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5NLGo_p6h3a)